# React images not loading on multi-site page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

I'm developing a multi-page website in React. 
The issue is that when I go from 1 page to another I lose the images. They work fine on the root page `"/"` but when I go to another page ( company1 ) the logo is lost.

In the browser console I **ONLY** get an error when I navigate to `company1`:
`company1.jpg:1 GET http://localhost:8080/company/images/company1.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

I can't see what's going wrong here - I'm importing the images directly in the `Navbar.js` component.

**My file structure**

```
└public
│   + index.html  
|
└src
|   └───components
|   │       +  Navbar.js
|   |       +  Footer.js
|   |
|   └───img
|   │   └───companies
|   |   |    +  company1.jpg
|   |   |    +  company2.jpg
|   |   + logo.png
|   │   
|   └───pages
|   |     +  Home.js
|   |     +  Company1.js
|   |     +  Company2.js
|   |
|   └───routes
|   │     +  AppRouter.js
|   │
|   +  app.js
|
+ webpack.config.js
```

**routes/AppRouter.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import Home from "../pages/Home";
import Company1 from "../pages/Company1";
import Company2 from "../pages/Company2";

const AppRouter = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/company/company1" component={Company1} />
        <Route path="/company/company2" component={Company2} />
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

**/pages/Home.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
export default class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar company="GROUP PAGE" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**/pages/Company1.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
const Company1 = () => (
  <div>
    <Navbar company="Company1" />
  </div>
);

export default Company1 ;
```

**/components/Navbar.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import logo from "../img/logo.png";

const Navbar = props => (
  <nav>
      <Link className="navbar-brand to="/">
        <img src={logo} width="120" height="50" alt="group" />
        <span>{props.company}</span>
      </Link>
  </nav>
);

export default Navbar;
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/app.js",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: "babel-loader",
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "url-loader",
            options: {
              limit: 8000, // Convert images < 8kb to base64 strings
              name: "images/[hash]-[name].[ext]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: "cheap-module-eval-source-map",
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```

Comment: Your file structure doesn't correspond to the error or your `webpack.config.js`. Typo?

Comment: @jayarjo yep good point - That was a typo - I've updated the actual file structure now

Answer (score 0):

If the images are inside the src/assets folder you can use require.

```
const img = require('../../img.png');
```

You can also do this inline

```
<img src={require('../../img.png')} />
```

Comment: what's the difference with using `require` vs `import` ?